# App crashes when the bottom navigation menu hit twice in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

When I hit one of my bottom navigation menus **twice**, the app crashes with the following error. I can navigate through each menu in the bottom navigation without errors, everything works fine. I can hit all other menus twice and there is no error. It's the first fragment that loads when the app opens and there is no issue then.
When I hit this particular menu once again when I am in that fragment, the app crashes.

```
2021-07-02 19:43:43.904 20000-20000/com.trad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.trad, PID: 20000
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.trad.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment$onCreateOptionsMenu$1.onQueryTextChange (DashboardFragment.kt:329)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1187)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1725)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:11785)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6965)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6761)
    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:145)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6713)
    at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:6580)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:22288)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4805)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4805)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4805)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4805)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:22266)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.restoreActionViewStates(MenuBuilder.java:412)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1917)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2176)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:268)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1010)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:809)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:740)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:995)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

The code that the error pointing at with >>DashboardFragment.kt:329<< is `rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()` and it part of the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

Edit:

```
    class DashboardFragment : BaseFragment() {

    var srchProductsList: ArrayList<Product> = ArrayList()
    var adList: ArrayList<Ads> = ArrayList()
    var srchTempProductsList: ArrayList<Product> = ArrayList()
    var newView: String = "ListView"


    private lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.fbDashboard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grid_view)
        binding.fbDashboard.setOnClickListener {

            if (newView == "ListView") {
                newView = "GridView"
                fb_dashboard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_view)
            } else {
                newView = "ListView"
                fb_dashboard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grid_view)
            }

            onResume()

        }
        return binding.root


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId

        when (id) {

            R.id.action_settings -> {

                startActivity(Intent(activity, SettingsActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }

            R.id.action_cart -> {
                startActivity(Intent(activity, CartListActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }

            R.id.admin_panel -> {

                startActivity(Intent(activity, AssignPINCodeActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

      srchProductsList.clear()
        srchTempProductsList.clear()
        getDashboardItemsList()
    }


    private fun getDashboardItemsList() {
        // Show the progress dialog.
        showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

        getDashboardItemsList2()
    }


    fun successDashboardItemsList(dashboardItemsList: ArrayList<Product>) {

        hideProgressDialog()

        if (dashboardItemsList.size > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Total " + dashboardItemsList.size + " products loaded",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.GONE

            rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager =
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            rv_dashboard_items.setHasFixedSize(true)

            val adapter = DashboardItemsListAdapter(requireActivity(), dashboardItemsList, newView)
            rv_dashboard_items.adapter = adapter

            adapter.setOnClickListener(object :
                DashboardItemsListAdapter.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(position: Int, product: Product) {

                    val intent = Intent(context, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, product.product_id)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_OWNER_ID, product.user_id)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            })

        } else {
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    }


    fun successDashboardItemsListListView(dashboardItemsList: ArrayList<Product>) {

        hideProgressDialog()

        if (dashboardItemsList.size > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Total " + dashboardItemsList.size + " products loaded",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.GONE

            rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(context)
            rv_dashboard_items.setHasFixedSize(true)

            val adapter = DashboardItemsListAdapter(requireActivity(), dashboardItemsList, newView)
            rv_dashboard_items.adapter = adapter

            adapter.setOnClickListener(object :
                DashboardItemsListAdapter.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(position: Int, product: Product) {

                    val intent = Intent(context, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, product.product_id)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PRODUCT_OWNER_ID, product.user_id)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            })

        } else {
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)

        val item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_search_bar)
        val searchView = item?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                srchTempProductsList.clear()
                val searchKey = query
                if (searchKey != null) {
                    if (searchKey.isNotEmpty()) {
                        srchProductsList.forEach {
                            if (it.description.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                                    .contains(searchKey)
                            ) {
                                srchTempProductsList.add(it)
                            }
                        }
                        rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    } else {

                        srchTempProductsList.clear()
                        srchTempProductsList.addAll(srchProductsList)
                        rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    }
                }

                return false

            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

                srchTempProductsList.clear()
                val searchText = newText!!.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())

                if (searchText.isNotEmpty()) {
                    srchProductsList.forEach {
                        if (it.description.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchText)) {
                            srchTempProductsList.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                    rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                } else {
                    srchTempProductsList.clear()
                    srchTempProductsList.addAll(srchProductsList)
                    rv_dashboard_items.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }

                return false

            }

        })

    }

    private fun getDashboardItemsList2() {
        val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        mFireStore.collection(Constants.PRODUCTS)
            .get() 
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val product = i.toObject(Product::class.java)!!
                    product.product_id = i.id
                    srchProductsList.add(product)

                }
                srchTempProductsList.addAll(srchProductsList)

                if (newView == "ListView") {
                    successDashboardItemsListListView(srchTempProductsList)
                } else {
                    successDashboardItemsList(srchTempProductsList)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
    }

}
```

Comment: `rv_dashboard_items` must be null. Is it a synthetic property?

Comment: `viewbinding` . I have this >>  `private lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding`

Comment: Can you show how you declare and initialize `rv_dashboard_items`?

Comment: `rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
  rv_dashboard_items.setHasFixedSize(true)`

Comment: I mean, how do you declare and initialize the property, not how you assign its members.

Comment: I have updated the complete code of the `DashboardFragment.kt`. Maybe I made some serious mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't see `rv_dashboard_items` declared anywhere. Are you sure you aren't using synthetic properties? An error I do see is that you aren't setting the adapter on the recycler view until `successDashboardItemsList` is called, but you are using `!!` on that adapter in the listener that might get called first. That will cause a KotlinNullPointerException.

Comment: Thank you so much. I replaced `!!` with `?` and the issue is resolved and I do not see any other issue at the moment. If you post an answer I shall accept it as the answer. By the way, do you see any other mistake in my code? That is the entire code in that activity.

Comment: Your solution worked. Can you add answer then I'll mark it as the answer.